# Using @objc delegate methods with multiple arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I want to be able to pass multiple arguments to a `#selector()` method other than only the sender itself.

Say, I have a `UITextField` which has a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and I want some other class to be the delegate of this `UITapGestureRecognizer`. I write a delegate protocol for it called `SomeDelegateProcotol`. However, I also want to pass the instance of the UITextField to the delegate upon tap. I figured things might look something like this:

```swift
// The delegate
class Delegate: SomeDelegateProcotol {

    private let textField = TextField()

    func handleTapFromView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, textField: UITextField) {
        print("Hey! I should handle the tap from the user.")
    }

    init() {
       textField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

```swift
// The protocol
@objc protocol SomeDelegateProtocol {
    @objc func handletapFromView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, textField: UITextField)
}
```

```swift
class TextField: UITextField {
    weak var delegate: SomeDelegateProtocol?

    override init(frame: CGSize) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        ...
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: delegate!, 
            action: #selector(delegate!.handleTapFromView(_:, textField: 
            self)))
    } 
}
```

However, this is not the right syntax, as `handleTapFromView(_:, textField: self)` is invalid. This raises the following questions to which I haven't found a solution yet:

- What exactly means this syntax? `(_:)`. I assume it's passing itself, but the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not created yet?
- How do I successfully pass the TextField instance to the delegate alongside the sender?

Comment: You can send this textfield instance by putting it in a Dictionary.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, could you please elaborate on that statement? How exactly could I do this? And why would I use a dictionary?

Comment: You can create dictionary like dict = {"textfield" : <textfield instance here>, "key" : <value>}, and pass this dictionary into parameter of delegate function.

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the benefit of using a dictionary over passing the instance itself directly

Comment: It is easiest way of doing, of-course there many more ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest keeping things as simple as this,

```
protocol SomeDelegateProtocol: class {
    func handletapFromView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, textField: UITextField)
}

class TextField: UITextField {
    weak var someDelegate: SomeDelegateProtocol?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc private func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.someDelegate?.handletapFromView(sender, textField: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach slipped my mind completely somehow.. Thank you! Just out of curiosity, do you know if it is possible what I was trying to achieve?

Comment: It was not possible as the only valid methods for selector are `func handleGesture() & func handleGesture(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)`

Comment: a solution from heaven